# WAMP - Unwanted prefix https:// on localhost url even though not having any htaccess on root folder

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I have some projects on my wamp/www/ directory. Some of my projects, when accessed through 127.0.0.1/project_name or localhost/project_name automatically adds an https:// prefix on the url so it becomes https://127.0.0.1/project_name, which then causes the site to be unreachable.

These projects DOESN'T have any .htaccess files on their root directories. While this may be true to some of my projects, some of my projects are ok and doesn't add unwanted https:// prefix on url.

I'm using WAMP 3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

One more thing. Make sure you **remove** this from you `head` section if you have it. It forces the resources (jpg, css, js) to load with `https`.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Answer (score -1):

Apache web servers are able to rewrite/redirect incoming requests/urls. Globally this behavior can be set using the httpd.conf or php.ini files for example.

Typically when the default or global behavior needs to be modified for a certain directory, an .htaccess file can be used to define different behavior for requests to that directory/project.

Look in the root of the projects that are being redirected as https:// for an .htaccess file . If you see the lines below in the .htaccess file, you can remove them or modify them to ensure the server handles requests as you expect.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi sir, my projects doesn't have any htaccess on their root. thanks :)

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is to look at the httpd.conf file to see if there is anything that sticks out for the given ports/locations for the individual projects that are behaving differently. It's difficult offer more advice without knowing what Wamp Server variant you are using and the types of projects etc.

Comment: @Luke He wants to remove https prefix, not to add it.